# Why can't the following function template code compile?

Tags: c++, templates

I wrote a function template `f` which takes a vector iterator as a parameter:

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
void f(vector<T>::iterator it)
{

}

int main()
{
    vector<int> v;
    f(v.begin());
}
```

Compiling it with gcc failed, the error message is very hard to understand:

[image]

What's the cause of the compilation error and how can I fix it?

Comment: You haven't given the parameter passed to f a name.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of error messages — they're hard to read, let alone understand, especially on cell phones.

Comment: The error message you show doesn't match the error output you show. Please create a proper [mcve], and copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete error output of that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  [But it does](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b4469323f8bd5cbe).

Comment: @jrok In a way yes, but the shown code doesn't have a call `f(it)` on line 17, and `f` is not on line 6.

Comment: @abigaile: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords also applies.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Good eye, mate ;)

Comment: You need to declare `template <typename T> void f(typename vector<T>::iterator)` and call it via `f<int>(v.begin())`,  since the compiler can't deduce the template argument. See the [Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/xrsZn2).